# How to connect to Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect my application hosted in Azure to a database also hosted in Azure. I get an error please find the below

> "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server."

when the app is trying to query the database.

Before hosting the app and the database in Azure (the app worked on localhost) my connection string to on premise SQL server database looked like this:

```
Data Source=DESKTOP-LCO4GKN;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|BakaAppDb.mdf;Initial Catalog=BakaAppDb;Integrated Security=True
```

After migrating the database to Azure and creating a user with login I entered the connection string like this:

```
Server=tcp:betterorgappserver.database.windows.net;Database=BetterOrgAppDatabase_Dogfood;User ID=login1user;Password=*******;
```

The question is how should the connection string look like? I am using entity framework in my app, if that might influence its look.

**EDIT**

After some time I "managed" to get error specifying that the login for user failed

> Login failed for user 'login1user1'.

This is the stack trace:

```
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +347
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +217
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
   and so on...
```

I guess it means I gave the privileges to the user incorrectly. So now the question is how do I add a new user with privileges to access the database?

I did it according to this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/cs-cz/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/#granting-database-access-to-a-login

Thanks

Comment: You error message does not provide much information. Please get the log file from Kudu console of you web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
Make sure to **allow the client firewall for your application from the database server**

Also, you can try adding a Data Connection to your Web App:
[image]

You can see the connection string on the portal if you navigate to the SQL Database, your connection string should look like:

> Server=tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=yourdatabase;User
>   ID=yourlogin@yourserver;Password={yourpassword};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection
>   Timeout=30;

You can view the Server admin login on the portal as well[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It gives me the same 502 error as at the beginning though.

Comment: 502 is caused in general by a timeout. In this case, you need to do is to look into your application and try to identify what part of the application is so slow or is triggering a crash

Comment: did you allow the client firewall for your application from the database server?

Comment: Yes, I did that, however when I changed the range to cover my whole private network.. Thanks!

Comment: Will you please edit the answer to include the stuff in comments, I will mark it as accepted then.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelVakoč which stuff would you like me to include? the firewall?